# Create an effect to make element fadeIn and fadeOut without using fadeToggle()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

You see, I use `if else` to achieve that goal, it just not works. I think I might make some mistakes. These codes are from W3Schools, and I changed it into this look.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("button").text() == "Click to fade in boxes")
    $("button").click(function() {
      $("#div1").fadeIn();
      $("#div2").fadeIn();
      $("#div3").fadeIn();
      $("button").text("Click to fade out boxes");
    });
  else
    $("button").click(function() {
      $("#div1").fadeOut();
      $("#div2").fadeOut();
      $("#div3").fadeOut();
      $("button").text("Click to fade in boxes");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Demonstrate fadeIn() with different parameters.</p>
<button>Click to fade in boxes</button>
<br>
<br>
<div id="div1" style="width:80px;height:80px;display:none;background-color:red;"></div>
<br>
<div id="div2" style="width:80px;height:80px;display:none;background-color:green;"></div>
<br>
<div id="div3" style="width:80px;height:80px;display:none;background-color:blue;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put `if/else` inside the `click` event. Because, when you put it outside of `click` (the way you did), just one of `click` event handlers will get attached. See:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // in document.load, this condition will be true
  if ($("button").text() == "Click to fade in boxes")
    // so you will have this function attached
    $("button").click(function() {
      // your stuffs
    });
  // but this one is false
  else
    // so this line, never get executed
    $("button").click(function() {
      // your stuffs
    });
});
```

As you can see, just first group of your code (`fadeIn()` stuffs) will get executed. So, change your code to:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("button").click(function() {
     if ($("button").text() == "Click to fade in boxes") {
       $("#div1").fadeIn();
       $("#div2").fadeIn();
       $("#div3").fadeIn();
       $("button").text("Click to fade out boxes");
     } else {
       $("#div1").fadeOut();
       $("#div2").fadeOut();
       $("#div3").fadeOut();
       $("button").text("Click to fade in boxes");
     }
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Demonstrate fadeIn() with different parameters.</p>
<button>Click to fade in boxes</button>
<br>
<br>
<div id="div1" style="width:80px;height:80px;display:none;background-color:red;"></div>
<br>
<div id="div2" style="width:80px;height:80px;display:none;background-color:green;"></div>
<br>
<div id="div3" style="width:80px;height:80px;display:none;background-color:blue;"></div>
```

And if you are looking for a shorter and cleaner code (as other users mentioned), you can do this (without a huge change in your code):

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("button").click(function() {
     if ($("button").text() == "Click to fade in boxes") {
       $("#div1, #div2, #div3").fadeIn(); // this will affect all div1, div2, and div3
       $("button").text("Click to fade out boxes");
     } else {
       $("#div1, #div2, #div3").fadeOut(); // this one too.
       $("button").text("Click to fade in boxes");
     }
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Demonstrate fadeIn() with different parameters.</p>
<button>Click to fade in boxes</button>
<br>
<br>
<div id="div1" style="width:80px;height:80px;display:none;background-color:red;"></div>
<br>
<div id="div2" style="width:80px;height:80px;display:none;background-color:green;"></div>
<br>
<div id="div3" style="width:80px;height:80px;display:none;background-color:blue;"></div>
```

Comment: Would you please tell me why can't I put it out of click() event!

Comment: @ChangeChang u'r wellcome. If it helped you to resolve your problem, so accept it plz.

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten your code using `.fadeToggle()` as well as ternary operator inside the `.text()` callback function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div1,#div2,#div3").fadeToggle();
        $(this).text(function() {
            return $(this).text() == "Click to fade in boxes" ? "Click to fade out boxes" : "Click to fade in boxes"
        });
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wL5u9yk2/)**

Comment: look at the title `without using fadeToggle()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are checking the condition only on page load, you need to test it inside the click handler

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    if ($(this).text().trim() == "Click to fade in boxes") {
      $("#div1, #div2, #div3").fadeIn();
      $(this).text("Click to fade out boxes");
    } else {
      $("#div1, #div2, #div3").fadeOut();
      $(this).text("Click to fade in boxes");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Demonstrate fadeIn() with different parameters.</p>
<button>Click to fade in boxes</button>
<br>
<br>
<div id="div1" style="width:80px;height:80px;display:none;background-color:red;"></div>
<br>
<div id="div2" style="width:80px;height:80px;display:none;background-color:green;"></div>
<br>
<div id="div3" style="width:80px;height:80px;display:none;background-color:blue;"></div>
```

---

Or shorter

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $divs = $("#div1, #div2, #div3");
  var $btn = $("button").click(function() {
    if ($btn.text().trim() == "Click to fade in boxes") {
      $divs.fadeIn();
      $btn.text("Click to fade out boxes");
    } else {
      $divs.fadeOut();
      $btn.text("Click to fade in boxes");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Demonstrate fadeIn() with different parameters.</p>
<button>Click to fade in boxes</button>
<br>
<br>
<div id="div1" style="width:80px;height:80px;display:none;background-color:red;"></div>
<br>
<div id="div2" style="width:80px;height:80px;display:none;background-color:green;"></div>
<br>
<div id="div3" style="width:80px;height:80px;display:none;background-color:blue;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code :

```
 $("button").on("click", function() {
    if ($("button").text() == "Click to fade in boxes") {
        $("#div1").fadeIn();
        $("#div2").fadeIn();
        $("#div3").fadeIn();
        $("button").text("Click to fade out boxes");
    }
    else {
        $("#div1").fadeOut();
        $("#div2").fadeOut();
        $("#div3").fadeOut();
        $("button").text("Click to fade in boxes");
    }
});
```

You have attached the onClick event with the same button twice and that is why it was not working fine.

Comment: Would you please tell me why can't I use .click()?

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
      if ($("button").text() == "Click to fade in boxes"){
      $("#div1").fadeIn();
      $("#div2").fadeIn();
      $("#div3").fadeIn();
      $("button").text("Click to fade out boxes");}
      else {
      $("#div1").fadeOut();
      $("#div2").fadeOut();
      $("#div3").fadeOut();
      $("button").text("Click to fade in boxes");}
    });
});
I can't

Comment: You can also use .click(). There are some of the advantages of using .on over .click. Like You can easily remove the click event from the selector using .off("click", handler) if you have attached the event using .on("click", handler).

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        if($("#div1,#div2,#div3").is(':visible')){
            $("#div1,#div2,#div3").fadeOut();
            $("button").text("Click to fade in boxes");                
        }
        else{
            $("#div1,#div2,#div3").fadeIn();
            $("button").text("Click to fade out boxes");
        }
    });
});
```

NOTE: `$("#div1,#div2,#div3").is(':visible')` will return true even if one element is visible